# Import a client side module in NextJs

Tags: javascript, azure, next.js, server-side-rendering, dynamic-import

I am trying to import the @azure/communication-calling module to my NextJs application. Although I when I try to build the project I get this error: > Build error occurred
ReferenceError: window is not defined.

I tried to use dynamic import, but it didn't work for me because it returns react.componenttype element but I need my original module. Can someone help how can I achieve this?

```
const AzureCommunicationCallingSDKLocalVideoStream = dynamic(
() =>
import("@azure/communication-calling").then(
  (module) => module.LocalVideoStream
),
{ ssr: false }
);
```

Comment: as far as I know, dynamic imports work if the return value is a component

Comment: Thanks! I managed to solve the problem by using import()